# Typescript, define object that is the product of all the types in array

Tags: typescript, types

Is it possible to create a generic type that is the sum of all types in an array. For example typing this function that concatenates key/value pairs

```
myFunction([{hi: 'str'}, {world: 123}]) => {hi: string, world: number}
```

Where also this type is a dynamic construction, so ideally it should be something like

```
const myFunction = <T>(args: key value pair of T[]): T
```

Comment: If by "dynamic" you mean *at runtime* then the type might not be that important.

Comment: Sorry, I mean when parameters have been applied it should infer T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
type RequiredPropertyNames<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends undefined ? never : K
}[keyof T]

// this is just a stub signature, append your implementation to its body
declare function myFunction<T>(args: T[]):
    { [K in RequiredPropertyNames<T>]: NonNullable<T[K]> }

const result = myFunction([{ hi: 'str' }, { world: 123 }]) 
// { hi: string; world: number; }
```